NPM install - ENOTFOUND _ React in Laravel
I am currently working on a Laravel 11 project, and want to include react components into it, however I keep getting this error when I run "npm install". My internet speed is 29mbps-Download and 18mbps-Upload. I have tried searching for solutions but I keep getting older feedback and is not solving my problem. Can someone assist please, I have tried everything I can. My OS is Linux ubuntu 24.04
    $npm install
    npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
    npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
    npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
    npm ERR! network request to 
    https://registry.npm.taobao.org/@popperjs%2fcore failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com
    npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
    npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
    npm ERR! network 
    npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
    npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/papa_amu/.npm/_logs/2024-04-25T07_12_24_413Z-debug-0.log

Uninstalled NodeJS and reinstall, downloaded another version. Installed NVM and tried to switch node versions , still not winning.
I tried to follow through videos of people who may have had similar issues, still I am not winning.
I tried to create a new project only with React , still I have an issue when I get to npm install
